# How do I filter a GlideRecord Query for tasks by a Change Request Field

Tags: servicenow

I've got code that is supposed to return all approved changes for certain CIs that are taking place at the moment of execution. The idea would be query the task_ci table and dot walk to the respective fields I need. Here's the code:

```
    var changes = new GlideRecord('task_ci');
    changes.addQuery('task.sys_class_name', 'change_request');
    changes.addQuery('task.approval','approved');
    changes.addQuery('ci_item', 'IN', items.join(','));
    changes.addQuery('task.active', true);
    changes.addQuery('task.start_date','<=', gs.nowDateTime());
    changes.addQuery('task.end_date','>=', gs.nowDateTime());
    changes.query();
```

The code seems to work fine except for the start and end date part. It pretty much ignores those. My guess is that since start_date and end_date are actually on the change request form (which extends from task), that they aren't accessible this way. Is there a way to use those fields in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change start_date and end_date are not directly available on task_ci table. You need to dot walk over the change request table and fetch it. To get the actual query, you can apply the filter a filter on the table and copy its query.

Query:

```js
  task.ref_change_request.start_date<=javascript:gs.nowDateTime()^task.ref_change_request.end_date>=javascript:gs.nowDateTime()
```

[Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgd6i.png)

The query was modified to match your criteria on Now (Current date/time) and applied to the script as below.

```js
    var changes = new GlideRecord('task_ci');
    changes.addQuery('task.sys_class_name', 'change_request');
    changes.addQuery('task.approval','approved');
    changes.addQuery('ci_item', 'IN', items.join(','));
    changes.addQuery('task.active', true);
    changes.addEncodedQuery('task.ref_change_request.start_date<=javascript:gs.nowDateTime()^task.ref_change_request.end_date>=javascript:gs.nowDateTime()');
    changes.query();
```

Here is the addQuery() version of the script

```js
    var changes = new GlideRecord('task_ci');
    changes.addQuery('task.sys_class_name', 'change_request');
    changes.addQuery('task.approval','approved');
    changes.addQuery('task.active', true);
    changes.addQuery('task.ref_change_request.start_date', '<=', 'javascript:gs.nowDateTime()');
    changes.addQuery('task.ref_change_request.end_date', '>=', 'javascript:gs.nowDateTime()');
    changes.query();
```

Comment: Can I just use addQuery? Do I have to use an encodedQuery to be able to use ref_change_request?

Comment: No it is not necessary. addEncodedQuery() is much cleaner version and you could reduce the 7 lines of code into just 3 lines.I prefer it often.

Comment: Here is the addQuery version
                                                                                                                                               
    var changes = new GlideRecord('task_ci');
    changes.addQuery('task.sys_class_name', 'change_request');
    changes.addQuery('task.approval','approved');
    changes.addQuery('task.active', true);
    changes.addQuery('task.ref_change_request.start_date', '<=', 'javascript:gs.nowDateTime()');
    changes.addQuery('task.ref_change_request.end_date', '>=', 'javascript:gs.nowDateTime()');
    changes.query();